# Laravel - Access middleware in RouteServiceProvider.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I need to separate the backend and frontend routes. To do so I created two different files in `\routes` directory for backend and frontend. In the `RouteServiceProvider.php` I want to know who the current user is in order to load its routes. I tried this

```
public function map()
{
    $this->mapApiRoutes();

    $this->mapWebRoutes();

    //
}

protected function mapWebRoutes()
{

    Route::middleware('auth')
         ->namespace($this->namespace)
         ->group(base_path('routes/backend.php'));
}
```

To load the route for middleware `auth` but it is not working. How can I do that?

Comment: Frontend -  admin panel?)  yii style?)

Comment: You load two route files, if you wish load only one route file you need to check it with if statement

Comment: just register all the routes ... why would routes need to be dynamic ... also would break route caching ... there is no reason to do this

Comment: @J.Doe How can I check the current user?

Comment: @lagbox just wanted to learn more. You mentioned good point about caching ;)

Comment: @Drupalist I don't know you database structure

Answer (score 1):

Add this file to your config folder https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/develop/config/logging.php

and add this to your .env file LOG_CHANNEL=stack

PHP artisan config:cache